# My USDZ export is very metallic, but blender model looks good

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am trying to turn this iclone model from blender into a USDZ file, but my USDZ exported models look very metallic and golden. I disabled the metallic nodes and they're all zero, so what is causing this?

I have been stuck doing this for months and I still can't figure it out..

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which USDZ exporter are you using?  Can you add a screen shot of your skin material node groups in the shader editor?  Can you add a screen shot of your export settings in the exporter?  Better yet, can you add a small blend file that shows the problems? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))